# ¿Un archivo minificado que tiene comentarios insertados, estará correctamente construido?

Tags: reactjs, npm, plugin, librería, build

Observando en la carpeta lib, un archivo **index.js** minificado observo que tiene comentarios insertados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces me pongo a dudar si estará correctamente construído o si los comentarios harán que el código se rompa en algún punto.

Sobretodo presté atención en la línea 9 donde el comentario se mezcla con el código de forma extraña:

```javascript
*/}var b="function"===typeof
```

Como datos adicionales la aplicación es de ***React***, y el plugin utilizado para minificar es el ***rollup-plugin-terser***  de npm, gracias por sus aportes.

Comment: No entiendo, que tienen de malo los comentarios ?? Un minify, hasta donde se, es exactamente el mismo código escrito e identado. Si lo minificas, no debería haber problema.

Comment: @Excorpion no digo que tengan algo de malo, mi duda es si el comentario interfiere porque yo tenía entendido que el minificar código significaba construirlo de modo que esté sin los comentarios como una forma de simplificarlo

Comment: Si tienes la duda no sería mejor borrar los comentarios y solucionas el problema?